# tag search library (ASP).NET

Tags: tags, search-engine

I seen some awful forums with horrible searching. Its highly important to be able to find things in my db/app. I am considering writing my own but before i do what do you guys think are good tag search libraries? C# .NET or possibly ASP.NET

NOTE: I do not want text searching, only tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lucene.NET I'm sure it can cover all that you want: http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/